# S3 PUT Bucket to a location endpoint results in a MalformedXML exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create an AWS s3 bucket using libCurl thusly:

Location end-point
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/");

Assembled RESTful HTTP header:

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1

Date:Fri, 18 Apr 2014 19:01:15 GMT

x-amz-content-sha256:ce35ff89b32ad0b67e4638f40e1c31838b170bbfee9ed72597d92bda6d8d9620
host:tempviv.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

x-amz-acl:private

content-type:text/plain

Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAISN2EXAMPLE/20140418/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=date;x-amz-content-sha256;host;x-amz-acl;content-type, Signature=e9868d1a3038d461ff3cfca5aa29fb5e4a4c9aa3764e7ff04d0c689d61e6f164

Content-Length: 163
```

The body contains the bucket configuration 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/&quot;>us-west-2

I get the following exception back.

`MalformedXML`The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

I've been able to carry out the same operation through the aws cli.

## Things I've also tried.

1) In the xml, used \ to escape the quotes (i.e., xmlns=\"http:.../\").

2) Not providing a CreateBucketConfiguration ("Although s3 documentation suggests this is not allowed when sending the request to a location endpoint").

3) A get service call to the same end point is listing all the provisioned buckets correctly.

Please do let me know if there is anything else I might be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that I was not transferring the entire xml across as was revealed by a wireshark trace. Once I fixed it, the problem went away.

Btw... escaping the quotes with a \ works but the & quot ; does not.